# Can't find CRS for Idaho DOT data in Qgis 2.18

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I downloaded a mile marker geojson from the Idaho DOT and the CRS is listed as 102605, which doesn't seem to exist outside of the DOT office.

This is the extent of the layer metadata:

XMin: 2254295.3529000003
YMin: 1199867.0130000003
XMax: 2743212.4619000005
YMax: 1980420.2782000005
Spatial Reference: 102605  (102605)

link to mapserver info:
https://gis.itd.idaho.gov/arcgisprod/rest/services/ArcGISOnline/MilePointLayers/MapServer/3

Comment: Did you try all Idaho CRS in QGIS? There's only 33. It shouldn't take long to test them. You could also try EPSG:102065, in case there's a typo in the metadata. The info on this page might help: [parameters for Idaho Transverse Mercator Projection](https://www.idwr.idaho.gov/GIS/IDTM/projection-parameters.html).

Comment: It looks like your layer is in Idaho Transverse Mercator. The parameters are described in [this](https://ita.idaho.gov/psg/s4210.pdf) document

Comment: The projection is included in GDAL 2.3.1 and gdal-dev as EPSG:102605 (although it is really an ESRI projection). You can get it from gisinternals https://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-2-3-1-mapserver-7-2-0.zip , but unfortunately QGIS is currently delivered with GDAL 2.2.4.

Comment: The projection is now included in the EPSG registry as `EPSG:8826 NAD83 / Idaho Transverse Mercator`. It will take some time until it finds its way in the GDAL release.